# Shading time series data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have two Pandas dataframes: svt_data and asp_data. The first is time series data and the second is specific times in that series. I can plot the time series data no problem using `svt_data.plot()`. I want to then shade the specific times from the second data frame.

In the past I have done this, not using pandas dataframes but rather native python lists, by iterating over the elements of the list and using matplotlib's `plt.axvline` function. However, when I iterate over the dataframe elements and use this function, it produces two figures instead of one. It shades the specific times from the second dataframe on one graph and gives me the time series on another graph.

How can I get them on the same plot?

```py
    from numpy import *
    from pandas import *
    import pylab as plt

    svt_data = read_csv("D:\\Archives\\workspace\\sizeTimeData.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["time", "size"])
    asp_data = read_csv("D:\\Archives\\workspace\\asperityFailTimes.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["asp1"])

    for i in asp_data.asp1:
        plt.axvline(i,color=(0,1,0),alpha='0.5')

    svt_data.plot(x='time', y="size", color="black")
    plt.show()
```

Edit: Here is what a similar graph looks like having produced it using lists instead of dataframes.

[image: img]

I've switched to pandas because my data sets are getting larger and larger and it is taking unreasonable amounts of time to plot things and even to read in the data.

[Zoomed in on one cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFOmD.png)

Comment: How do you want to shade the timestamps? Can you sketch what you expect?

Comment: I've edited the question to include an image showing what I'm trying to reproduce.

Comment: That looks like a bar plot, not `svt_data.plot`. And the shaded parts are *time periods*.

Comment: The image was produced using ```plt.plot(time,size,"k-")```; it only looks like a bar plot because of the density of points and the "k-" line style. And they only look like time periods again because of the density. In a higher resolution image you would be able to see that it is only individual time steps being identified.

Comment: Last question, does `asp_data` occur in chunks? like `1,2,3, 8,9,10, 15,16,17` as it appears in the plot?

Comment: That depends on the initial conditions of the simulation, which is precisely what I'm investigating now. Usually, yes, the ```asp_data``` is clustered around the spikes in the time series data, however I'm trying to look now at a run where this is not the case and the ```asp_data``` have no significant clustering whatsoever. Even in the clustered data however, it is important to be able to pick out specific times in the analysis. I've added another image to the question showing a higher resolution on one of the clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) creates a new figure by default.
If you just switch the plotting command, plotting the data from the dataframe *before* and the lines *after*, you will get a single figure.

```
svt_data.plot(x='time', y="size", color="black")

for i in asp_data.asp1:
    plt.axvline(i,color=(0,1,0),alpha='0.5')
```